# Target to the mean encoding based on groups

Tags: python, group-by, encoding, mean

I have a data set that has some categorical values, also it has an item_id and target:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Salt Lake City','a', 1, 120], ['Seattle','b', 2, 120], ['San Franscisco','a', 3, 140], 
            ['Seattle','a', 3, 100], ['Seattle', 'a', 2, 70], ['San Franscisco','a', 1, 100],['Salt Lake City','a', 1, 60], 
            ['San Franscisco', 'b', 2, 110], ['Seattle','b', 3, 100],['Salt Lake City','a', 3, 70] ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['City', 'Class', 'item_id','target'])
```

I want to do some transformations on Categorical features (target to the mean encoding), but in this case I want to take into account the item_id, group data based on the item_id and after apply mean encoding:

**Mean based Item_ID:**

```
from typing import List
class FeatureEngineeringCategoryToTargetMean:
    def __init__(self, features: List[str]):
        self.features = features

    def fit(self,
            X: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
        for feature in self.features:
            name = str(f"{feature}_target_mean")
            X[name] = 0
            mean = X["target"].groupby([X["item_id"], X[feature]]).mean()
        return self

    def transform(self, X: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        for tuple_element in mean.index:
            value = mean[tuple_element]
            X.loc[(X["item_id"] == tuple_element[0]) & (X[feature] == tuple_element[1]), name] = value
        return X
```

When I call the functions:

```
feature_engineering = FeatureEngineeringCategoryToTargetMean(features=['City', 'Class'])
feature_engineering.fit(X=df.copy())
data = feature_engineering.transform(X=df.copy())
```

I got the following outcome:
[image]

But I need to apply encoding on both City and Class column. In the **fit** function the mean is pandas series, I am not sure how I can save several outputs (in my example for both City and Class).

[image]

Comment: It's unclear. Your words, 'apply frequency encoding and category to mean encoding' can't be understood. And in 'save several series', what do you mean? Just storing into local variables? And, what is your 'another function'?

Comment: @relent95 I added some details to the description, basically I want to be able to calculate the mean values per item_id and target for each category of categorical variable and use it as fit (X, y) and predict(mean, X) so in case I am using test data without leakage of target.

Comment: It's still unclear. Most technical descriptions in your words can't be understood literally due to bad English. Anyway, you already stored mean values into the data frame as new columns. Why not using it in fit() or predict()?

Comment: @relent95 this is exactly my problem, if I want to use several categorical variables (in my example City/Class, I am not able to store several outputs in fit function. I added a class that I am trying to create, but here I am not sure how to use fit function when I have several categories.

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Comment: @JosefZ I tried to edit my post, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Your code is still not a [mre]. The ```transform()``` contains a syntax error. You need to differentiate between a working code which outputs the first table, and a non-working code. Anyway, now I understand your problem. You should edit your question saying like this, 'How can I store values of the ```mean``` in the ```fit()``` and use them in the ```transform()```?'

Answer (score 0):

You can store values of the `mean` into a member variable like this.

```
class FeatureEngineeringCategoryToTargetMean:
    def __init__(self, features):
        self.features = features
        self.mean_by_feature = {}

    def fit(self, X):
        for feature in self.features:
            mean = ...
            self.mean_by_feature[feature] = mean
        ...

    def transform(self, X):
        for feature in self.features:
            mean = self.mean_by_feature[feature]
            name = str(f"{feature}_target_mean")
            X[name] = 0
            for tuple_element in mean.index:
                ...
        return X
```

But it's way too complicated. I recommend doing like this.

```
for feature in ['City', 'Class']:
    means = X['target'].groupby([X['item_id'], X[feature]]).mean()
    X[feature + '_target_mean'] = df.apply(
        lambda row: means[row['item_id'], row[feature]],
        axis=1)
```